# Image flickering while zooming while using PinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zooming, pinchzoom

I use the below code to place an `<Image>` and `<Image.GestureRecognizers>` to make the zoom functionality.
The code behind for the event `PinchUpdated="PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated"` is also provided.
The zoom function works, but too much flickering while pinching.

**XAML :**

```
            <Image 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="pageIterator"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated"></PinchGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
```

**Code behind :**

```
        private void PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            double currentScale = 1;
            double startScale = 1;
            double xOffset = 0;
            double yOffset = 0;

            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
                // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the X pixel coordinate.
                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
                Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                // Apply scale factor.
                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the below lines out of `PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated` method,otherwise you're essentially initializing these values every time you fire.

```
double currentScale = 1;
double startScale = 1;
double xOffset = 0;
double yOffset = 0;

private void PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
        {
            // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
            // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
        {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor.
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
        {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: currentScale should probably be a local variable in the `if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)` scope.

Comment: @Liron No, it also should  be outside the method,In fact, every time it fires, it fires `PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated` first, and then it goes into `if()`, and if you put it inside the method as local variable, you could see that it still starts at value1 every time.You could take a test，put it inside as local variable,and the call `Console.WriteLine("Current:=" + currentScale);` inside `if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)`,you will see it console `1` every time.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, I will check it and update here. I was in a guess for the initialization, but as I am new, I thought it is essential to be in the beginning.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT It worked for zoom in (when making big). But when zoom out (when making back to normal size), it is flickering again. It means I have to move the some code outside...

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Well, I'm checking the Xamarin Demo PinchGesture, hope I can get clear idea looking at the code. I will update.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - you already have that value saved in Content.Scale, so I would have kept currentScale as a local variable and initialized it to be `double currentScale = Content.Scale` in that scope.